# How to use switchToLatest() in AnyPublisher() using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I've been trying to use switchToLatest() in AnyPublisher<T, Error>.
To cancel the previous Network Request.

As switchToLatest() only available in Publisher() not able to use in AnyPublisher().
I m very new to combine, any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code,

```
var pickupDeliveryPlaces: CurrentValueSubject<[PickupDeliveryPlaces], Never> = .init([])
private var disposeBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

private func fetchPlacesPredictions(input: String) {
    deliveryService.fetchPickupDeliveryPlacesCombine(input: input)
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .map { $0.places ?? [] }
        .delay(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .switchToLatest() -> Throws error here
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
              print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
                Debug.log("Error while fetching addresses: \(error)")
                self.error.send(SSServiceError(fuzzMessage: "Something went wrong, give it another fry… um, try!"))
            case .finished:
              print("Received Completion")
            }
          }, receiveValue: { [weak self] places in
            print(places, "---places")
            self?.pickupDeliveryPlaces.send(places)

          })
        
        .store(in: &disposeBag)
}

 func fetchPickupDeliveryPlacesCombine(input: String, shouldRefresh: Bool = false, debug: Bool = false) -> AnyPublisher<PickupDeliveryPlacesResponse?, SSServiceError> {
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "input": input,
        "filter": String(true)
    ]

    let endPoint = SSNextBaseService.Endpoints.getPlaces
    let request = nextBaseService.getRequest(endPoint, parameters: parameters)
    return service.fetchObservableCombine(request: request, serviceType: .fuzz, shouldRefresh: shouldRefresh, debug: debug)
        .map { ($0 as ResultWrapper<PickupDeliveryPlacesResponse?>).result}
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One variant would be to explicitly tell your `map` to return an `AnyPublisher` (see below). Then you can use `switchToLatest()` as you like.

```swift
...
deliveryService.fetchPickupDeliveryPlacesCombine(input: input)
        .compactMap { $0 }
        // Just as an example, pseudocode. 
        .map { deliveryPlaces -> AnyPublisher<Places, Error> in 
             deliveryPlaces.places ?? [] 
        }
        .delay(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .switchToLatest() -> No errors now
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
...
```

Hopefully I could help you.